# Blocking FTP access with iptables

Tags: iptables, ftp

I am trying to set up iptables to log connection attempts to port 21 on a server, then deny the connection. The logging works, but I can't get iptables to actually reject the connection or drop the packets, no matter what I try.

Logging rule:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix `FTP connection: '
```

I've tried getting iptables to DROP and REJECT port 21 as the second rule, but it doesn't work and I can still reach the server on 21.

```
2    REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

is one, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ftp \
         -j LOG -log-level 7 --log-prefix 'FTP connection: '
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ftp -j DROP
```

or:

```
iptables -t filter -N FTP
iptables -t filter -A FTP -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'FTP connection: '
iptables -t filter -A FTP -j DROP
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ftp -j FTP
```